# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isHydrating') - storybook with vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, storybook

When I am running storybook I have got an error in every component:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isHydrating')
    at VueComponent.mounted (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js:1855:41)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:4528:61)
    at callHook$1 (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3842:13)
    at Object.insert (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:2911:13)
    at invokeInsertHook (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:6800:38)
    at Vue.patch [as __patch__] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:7011:9)
    at Vue._update (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3588:25)
    at Vue.updateComponent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:3689:16)
    at Watcher.get (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:4074:33)
    at Watcher.run (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:4150:30)
```

[image: Webpack is build successfully but inside storybook there is an error]

## Running script

`vue-cli-service storybook:serve -p 6006 -c config/storybook`

## Dependecies

This project is setup mainly for common components so most of packages are installed as dev dependecy

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.26",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.26",
        "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
        "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
        "@storybook/vue": "^6.0.26",
        "vue-cli-plugin-storybook": "~2.1.0",
        "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vuetify": "^2.6.0",
        "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
        "vue-svg-loader": "^0.17.0-beta.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-template-loader": "^1.1.0",
        ...
},
"peerDependencies": {
        "sass": ">=1.3",
        "vue": ">=2.4",
        "vue-class-component": ">=7",
        "vue-property-decorator": ">8",
        "vue-template-loader": "^1.1.0",
        "vuetify": "^2.6.7"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "vue-loader": "^15.10.0"
    }
```

I have added *resolutions* becouse somewhere I read that it might help. It didn't. I susspect that there might be some problem with vuex or vuex-persistant-store...

Thanks in advance for any advice ;)